# undefined control sequence \includegraphics problem

Tags: floats

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \title{Bus Rapid Transit}
    \author{Mohamed Mirza}
    \date{May 9, 2018}
\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{What is a Transportation System?}

\subsection{What do Transportation Systems mean for the Urban Environment?}

\section{What is Mobility within a Transportation Framework?}

\section{Current State of Transportation within the Greater Toronto and Hamilton Area (GTHA)}

The Greater Toronto and Hamilton Area (GTHA) is served by GO Transit, a
regional public transit system operated by Metrolinx, and several public
transport agencies within the province of Ontario, e.g. the HSR and the Toronto
Transit Commission, TTC. According to The Star, traffic congestion results in
delays that amount to \$500 to \$650 million per year. Despite the level of
traffic congestion experienced in this area, it is home to several different
forms of urban modes. The urban modes that exist within the GTHA are:

\begin{itemize}
    \item BRT system
    \item Light Rail Transit, LRT, system
    \item Bus
    \item Intercity Rail
    \item Airlines
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{3.jpg}
        \caption{Toronto Streetcar.}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

The shear number of urban modes currently present in the GTHA represent how
transportation plays a pivotal part in the daily life of commuters.

\subsection{Categorizing the Current Traffic Congestion Problem}

\subsubsection{Traffic Congestion: A Weak Link Problem?}

\section{Fundamentals of a BRT System}

Talk about them

\subsection{Is Implementing a BRT System Economically Feasible?} % dimension

\subsubsection{Funding Strategies}

\end{document}
```

Anyone know why I constantly get this error. I am new to LaTeX and have been
playing around with it for the past two days. Any help would be greatly
appreciated. Thank You.

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please instead of (not readable) image of your complete provide small document beginning with `\documentcalss{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. do you load package `graphicx`?

Comment: @Zarko `\documentclass{...}` And perhaps `\usepackage{graphicx}` will solve the issue.

Comment: already had \documentclass{...}; I don't know how to show the entire code on StackExchange - Do I use the code or HTML option?

Comment: @MohamedMirza, we don't know which document class you use (instead dots should be its name, for example `article`), so i ask you for complete but small document with part regarding inclusion of image (not image of its code, image is not helpful). we also don't know, how you compile your document. with `latex`? with `pdflatext`? without of this information we can only guess what is your problem. help us to help you!

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the reply, I've included my code and I am viewing it with pdflatex

Comment: In order to use the `\includegraphics` directive, one *must* load the `graphicx` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me convert my coments to an answer:

- the best way to show what is your problem is to provide minimal working example (mwe). in your case it is:

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
  \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
      \begin{center}
          \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}%{3.jpg}
          \caption{Toronto Streetcar.}
      \end{center}
  \end{figure}
  \end{document}
  ```

  which gives error

  ```
   ! Undefined control sequence.
   1.9     \includegraphics
                            [width=2in]{example-image}%{3.jpg}`
  ```
- from it follows that in preamble (as i suspect) is missing the package `graphicx`. added it as `\usepackage{graphicx}` in document preamble solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}  % <--- added

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}%{3.jpg}
        \caption{Toronto Streetcar.}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

note: since we havent your image `3.jpg` in my mwe i use `example-image`, which is provided by package `mwe`. in your document you not need to use extension of your image file, however image name `3` is unappropriated. better is select some word (synonym) for image name.

Comment: Torbjørn T., thank you very much for editing my answer. how you manage to format it ( i don't know how to insert code in list as you do)?